# Conditional number: exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Let's say we've got a $202 \times 202$ matrix $A$ for which $||A||_2=100$ and $||A||_F=101$ (the Frobenius norm). How can we find the sharpest bound (lower) on the 2-norm condition number of $A$?

**Edit:**

$\kappa(A)=||A||_2\,||A^{-1}||_2$

Now, there is a theorem that says $||A||_2=\sigma_1$ (the highest singular value), $||A^{-1}||_2=\sigma_r^{-1}$ ($\sigma_r$ the lowest singular value) and $||A||_F=\sqrt{\sigma_1^2+\ldots+\sigma_r^2}$ (with $r=rank(A)$).

Any hints/solutions will be much appreciated!

Comment: $\|A^{-1}\|_2$ is $1/\sigma_r$, not $\sigma_r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. $\|A^{-1}\|_2=\frac{1}{\sigma_{202}}$, not $\sigma_{202}$. So, the question boils down to finding the *highest* possible value of $\sigma_{202}$.  Now $\sigma_1^2+\ldots+\sigma_{202}^2=101^2,\ \sigma_1^2=100^2$ and $\sigma_1\ge\sigma_2\ge\ldots\ge\sigma_{202}\ge0$. What is the greatest possible value of $\sigma_{202}$?